# After upgrade php version to 8, this error display

Tags: php, php-8

I am upgrading php 7 to php 8.0. In previous php version 7, this code working fine.

```
$child_parent['parent'][$resultData->parent_id]->child = 'Yes';
```

This above code working fine in php 7. Now I am upgading php version 8.0. In this new version it gives this error.

> An uncaught Exception was encountered Type: Error
>
> Message: Attempt to assign property "child" on null

Comment: This mean `$child_parent['parent'][$resultData->parent_id]` is `null` and you are trying to access `child` property on `null`. Go to previous step to check why it is null.

Comment: You should check your $child_parent['parent'] array and then check the value of $resultData->parent_id, because $child_parent['parent'][$resultData->parent_id] evaluate NULL, and try to assign a property on NULL was already an error in php7.

Comment: in php7, this code works fine : $child_parent['parent'][$resultData->parent_id]->child = 'Yes'; it echo "Yes". In php 8, it gives error.

Comment: It probably gave a warning before, rather than an error. PHP 8 is stricter, to make it harder to do silly things. Again, the solution is to find out why it's null and fix the bug

Comment: My question is "child" and "open_child" property are not present in code or key or value. Still it works fine in php 7. It is not working in php 8. @ADyson

Comment: Yes and I've already explained probably why it worked "fine"...because actually it probably didn't, it just didn't crash. Either that or the problem is unrelated to your upgrade, and it's actually just some different data causing it. Either way, you need to debug it and fix it. That's the bottom line. We can't tell you why it's null because we don't have all your data or all of the relevant code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't just assign property on non object.
This also errors on PHP 7 not just 8.

For example:

```
$arr = [];

$arr['parent'][1]->child = 'yes';
```

I'm trying to assign `child` property on non object. The `$arr['parent'][1]` is empty, not an object.
The result on PHP 7.0 - 7.4:

> Warning: Creating default object from empty value

The result on PHP 8.0+:

> Error: Attempt to assign property "child" on null

The difference between PHP 7.0+ and PHP 8.0+ is...
In PHP7.0+, The **Warning** level can still continue process
While in PHP 8.0+ this becomes **Error** level and will be stopped the process.
If you show all errors or log all error level, you will see that this is not just happens on PHP 8.0+.

To make it work (to assign property), your variable must be object. In my example, the `$arr['parent'][1]` must be object.

```
$arr = [];

$arr['parent'][1] = new \stdClass();
$arr['parent'][1]->child = 'yes';
```

In your case, both `$child_parent['parent'][$resultData->ModuleID]` and `$child_parent['parent'][$resultData->parent_id]` needed to declare as an object before assign the property.

```
if ($resultData->parent_id == 0) {
    $child_parent['parent'][$resultData->ModuleID] = $resultData;// I think $resultData is already an object.
    $child_parent['parent'][$resultData->ModuleID]->child = 'No';
} else {
    $child_parent['child'][$resultData->parent_id][$increment] = $resultData;
    $child_parent['parent'][$resultData->parent_id] = new \stdClass();// added
    $child_parent['parent'][$resultData->parent_id]->child = 'Yes';

    // your code
}
```

Comment: I also added $arr['parent'][1]->open_child = 'yes'; and $child_parent['parent'][$resultData->parent_id] = new \stdClass();  Your code is working. Thanks @vee .

Comment: You don't have to use `$arr['parent'][1]`. I just write this code for example only. Please read my description, it is already explained.